# Rails: has_many association with self through another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `users` table and a `contacts` table. These are the schema for the `contacts` table:

```
CREATE TABLE "contacts" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "user_id" integer, "contact_id" integer, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL, "users_id" integer);
CREATE INDEX "index_contacts_on_user_id" ON "contacts" ("user_id");
CREATE INDEX "index_contacts_on_contact_id" ON "contacts" ("contact_id");
CREATE INDEX "index_contacts_on_users_id" ON "contacts" ("users_id");
```

So basically a user can have many contacts, identified in the table by `contact_id`.

I defined the associations like this:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :users, foreign_key: :contact_id
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users, through: :contacts
end
```

Now the issue: when trying to retrieve an user's contacts calling the corresponding method, `@user.users`, I am getting the following error:

> Could not find the association :contacts in model User

What does this even mean? Why am I getting this error?

I would like some help to try to fix this problem. Also, is there a way I can rename the association so instead of calling `@user.users` I'd call `@user.contacts`, which would make more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out myself.

Solution:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :contacts, join_table: :contacts, class_name: 'User',
        foreign_key: :user_id, association_foreign_key: :contact_id
end
```

Comment: I love when people down votes with no arguments at all. That on top that this is the solution for my own question and it works.

Answer (score 1):

**Contacts table**

```
create_table :contacts do |t|
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :related_id
end
```

**Using has_and_belongs_to_many**

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, class_name: 'User',
   join_table: 'contacts', association_foreign_key: 'related_id'
end
```

**Using has_many through:**

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :related_id
  has_many :users, foreign_key: :user_id
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: :contacts
end
```

Comment: I already have a `contacts` table. How can I define the association with this table instead of one named `users_contacts`?

Comment: You need third table if you want `many-to-many` association between `users` and `categories`.

Comment: why? don't you see the association is with itself?

Comment: If I understood it correctly, you are trying to have many to many association between users and contacts? Am I wrong?

Comment: You are wrong. I am trying to have a many to many association beween `users` and `users`, it is a contact list. Users have other users as contacts, and these contacts have as well other users. This association is to be achieved through the `contacts` table. It's a reflexive many to many relation.

Comment: Then you need to create `contact` table with two fields: `owner_id` and `user_id`

Answer (score 1):

[`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) is used with three models, not two:

> This association indicates that the declaring model can be matched with zero or more instances of another model by proceeding through a *third* model.

The sample code goes on to explain that this can be used to coordinate physicians, appointments, and patients.

The `:through` attribute needs to be available as an association of its own:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

That's why you're getting the error: `has_many :users, through: :contacts` requires another association `contacts` on `User` (which you don't have).

For your problem, `has_many :contacts` may be enough.

Comment: I tried adding `has_many :contacts` but it messes up with the keys somehow and the retrieved associated items are the user to which the contacts belong instead of the contacts itself

Comment: I see. Can you please clarify in your question what you want to achieve? How are users and contacts related?

Comment: they are related the logical way, as a contact list. A user have a list of contacts, which are users themselves. And these users have other contacts as well, obviously.